# ArgumentError: invalid date when run minitest through jenkins execute shell

Tags: ruby, jenkins, minitest

I can run minitest through terminal command, but when I run the same command through jenkins, it throws "ArgumentError: invalid date" on all my test cases. I can't find any solutions from Google. Anyone can help me? And is here the right place to ask these questions?

```
ruby ../udesk_devops/autotest.rb 'develop' 'daily'
```

This can run correct through command line.
But will through 'invalid date' through jenkins

And in the process of executing through jenkins, I can see rollback in the log.
It seems the data is trying to go into mysql from fixtures.

```
Error:
test_问题库分类列表(管理员的问题库)(OpenApiV1::KnowledgeCatalogsControllerTest):
ArgumentError: invalid date
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/timecop-0.8.1/lib/timecop/time_extensions.rb:108:in `parse'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/timecop-0.8.1/lib/timecop/time_extensions.rb:108:in `parse_with_mock_date'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/conversions.rb:53:in `to_datetime'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:164:in `<=>'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:286:in `compare_with_coercion'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:570:in `=='
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:570:in `block (2 levels) in table_rows'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:569:in `each'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:569:in `block in table_rows'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:557:in `each'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:557:in `map'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:557:in `table_rows'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:473:in `block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:471:in `each'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:471:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:203:in `block in transaction'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `within_new_transaction'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:203:in `transaction'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:470:in `block in create_fixtures'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:274:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:457:in `create_fixtures'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:899:in `load_fixtures'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:859:in `setup_fixtures'
    /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:712:in `before_setup'
    /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/udesk_proj_week_daily/test/test_helper.rb:35:in `before_setup'
```

Comment: Hard to debug because I don't know your code, but it appears your problem is in:

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/udesk_proj_week_daily/test/test_helper.rb:35:in `before_setup'

Comment: I think it's my jenkins's fault But I don't know where is the fault

Comment: Without seeing your code, I don't know either.

Comment: FWIW there's a ticket regarding this: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/issues/190